# Setting a boolean flag with JQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, flags

I am trying to set a flag when a blockquote has been clicked. It does not appear to be working. Is isClicked considered Global, and if it is, is that not the correct way to change it from within a function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("blockquote").on("click", function() {
     setIsClicked();
   });
});

var isClicked = false;

function setIsClicked() {
   isclicked = true;
}
```

Comment: you have a typo there isClicked is lowercase in your function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function is trying to change a different variable - "isclicked" vs "isClicked".

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Been staring at the problem to closely I suppose.

Comment: Debugging tip: A linter or strict mode would have caught that for you.